# Jpa Specification, paging and filters

Tags: pagination

I just started working as a SW- developer, and I have been assigner to solve a bug.
We have some issue with the number of pages and elements returned.

Let me explain: in our UI the user can select the page size (10,20,50) and use some filters (multiple values inside the same filter (OR) plus multiple values in different filters (AND)) so we can obtain multiple information based on the filter or just 1 / no result if more filters are used.

In order to achieve this the developer used Jpa Specification (still a little bit unclear to me) for the filters and Page for the pagination.

The first issue (*issue1) was that without the if/else condition, we returned always

`meDetailsPage = meIdDetailsRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);`

and the totalPages counter went bananas when there is no filter.
I tryied to debug but it takes me to the JdkDynamicAopProxy(.class).invoke and then i lost my mind.
It returns the correct total number of pages only when is the last page (.isLast = true)

The code for the filters (Specification, pagination) is like this:

```
@NotNull
@Transactional
public Page<MyObject> getMyObjects(
    @NotNull final List<Filter> filterList,
    @NotNull final Pageable pageable) 
    {
        Specification<JpaMyEntity> spec = Specification.where((root, query, cb) -> {
        Join<JpaMyEntity, JpaFirstEntityToJoin> Join1 = root.join("firstEntityToJoin", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<JpaMyEntity, JpaSecondEntityToJoin> Join2 = root.join("secondEntityToJoin", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<JpaFirstEntityToJoin, JpaThirdElementToJoin> Join3 = Join1.join("thirdElementToJoin", JoinType.LEFT);
        Join<JpaThirdElementToJoin, JpaFourthEntityToJoin> Join4 = Join3.join("fourthEntityTOJoin", JoinType.LEFT);
        query.groupBy(root.get("id"));

        // Applying filters
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Filter filter : filterList) {
            switch (filter.getField()) {
                case "filter1", "filter1a" -> {
                    Predicate predicate = root.get(filter.getField()).in(filter.getValues());
                    predicates.add(predicate);
                }
                case "filter2" -> {
                    Predicate predicate = productIndividualSalesOrderJoin.get(filter.getField()).in(filter.getValues());
                    predicates.add(predicate);
                }
                case "filter3", "filter3a" -> {
                    Predicate predicate = productIndividualMonaEpoJoin.get(filter.getField()).in(filter.getValues());
                    predicates.add(predicate);
                }
                case "filter4" -> {
                    Predicate predicate = salesOrderItemProductionJoin.get(filter.getField()).in(filter.getValues());
                    predicates.add(predicate);
                }
                default -> throw new InvalidFilterException("Invalid filter field " + filter.getField() + " provided in params" );
                }
            }

            Predicate[] p = new Predicate[predicates.size()];
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(p));
        });
        Page<JpaMyEntity> meDetailsPage = null; // *Issue1
        if (filterList.isEmpty()) {
            meDetailsPage = meIdDetailsRepository.findAll(pageable);
        } else {
            meDetailsPage = meIdDetailsRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
        }

        return meDetailsPage.map(jpaMyEntity -> jpaMyEntity .toCore(
            true, true, true));
    }
```

After the merge and the query, the object obtained is something like this

```
MyObject {
    field1: value,
    field2: value,
    subObjects: [
        {
            subField1: value,
            subField2: value
        },
        {
            subField1: value,
            subField2: value
        }
    ],
    field3: value,
    ...
    }
```

For some reason the totalPages is counting the number of subObjects.
Why it does not like the empty filter and why is counting the subObjects?
Could it be something in the multiple joins?

Now the second issue is (and I think is related to the first one), since a single filter can accept more values (OR) if the number of values in the filter is greater than the total size of the page i have the same issue.val
For example, with page size = 5

filter1: [val1,..val4] -> totalPages is OK (.isLast = true)
filter1: [val1,..val6] -> totalPages is NOT OK(.isLast = false).

I am sorry I cannot post the original code..
And thanks for the help!

Actually I am pretty lost in the debug session, but the whole .invoke class make no (or little) sense to me so I am stucked..